# Monitor shared file access using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2, smb, network-share

**Background**

Using Windows' MMC's Shared Folders functionality I'm able to view any Open Files being accessed via shared folders.
This gives me a static view; I'd like to write a script (ideally PowerShell) to monitor this share and log the information of who connects to what & when to file.

I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2, so sadly `Get-SmbOpenFile` isn't available.

**Question**

Is there a way to view all files open over a share in Windows 2008 R2 using PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `net file` and `net session` instead:

```
& net file | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '^(\d+)\s+(.*)\s+(\w+)\s+(\d+)\s*$'
} | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'ID'    = $matches[1]
        'File'  = $matches[2].Trim()
        'User'  = $matches[3]
        'Locks' = $matches[4]
    }
}

& net session | Where-Object {
    $_ -match '^(\S+)\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s*$'
} | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
        'Client' = $matches[1]
        'User'   = $matches[2]
        'Type'   = $matches[3].Trim()
        'Open'   = $matches[4]
        'Idle'   = $matches[5]
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do you kill/close connection to specific file? Thank you.

Comment: @Borik Please post a question of your own.

Comment: Found it: For any one else looking how to Close File: 
net files $_.ID /close